# Getting error in python: Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '470.21'

Tags: python, int

i want adding and subtracting this type of data: $12,587.30.which returns answer in same format.how can do this ?

Here is my code example:

```
print(int(col_ammount2.lstrip('$'))-int(col_ammount.lstrip('$')))
```

I removed $ sign and convert it to int but it gives me base 10 error.

Comment: what is the input and expected output? do you want to retain the decimal points or round it up/down?

Comment: actually i have an excel file where i get data in this form
$470.21  $1,788.98 i want adding and subtracting this type of values. and want print them in same format.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you want to do arithmetic operations to the numbers (addition/subtraction) so you probably want them in `float` instead. The difference between an integer (`int`) and `float` is that integers do not carry decimal points.

Additionally, as @officialaimm mentioned you need to remove the commas too, for example

```
float('$3,333.33'.replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))
```

will give you

```
3333.33
```

So putting it into your code

```
print(float(col_ammount2.lstrip('$').replace(',', ''))
      - float(col_ammount.lstrip('$').replace(',', '')))
```

An additional note for when you parse a floating point number (same applies to integers too), you may want to watch out for empty values, i.e.

```
float('')
```

is bad. One of the things u can do in case `col_amount` and `col_amount2` may be empty at some point is default them to `0` if that happens

```
float(col_amount.lstrip(...).replace(...) or 0)
```

You also want to read this to know about workaround to problems you may face with floating point arithmetic https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: this is working.one more thing this code i use for calculation but after that how can i get data back in original format ?

Comment: if u mean turning it back to string then just use `str`, i.e. `str(33.3)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you are missing here. Firstly python `int(...)` cannot parse numbers with commas so you will need to remove commas as well by using `.replace(',','')`. Secondly `int()` cannot parse floating point values you will have to use `float(...)` first and after that maybe typecast it to int using `int` or `math.ceil`, `math.floor` appropriately as per your choice and needs.

Maybe something like this will solve your problem:

```
col_ammount2='$1,587.30'
col_ammount = '$2,567.67'
print(int(float(col_ammount2.lstrip('$').replace(',','')))-int(float(col_ammount.lstrip('$').replace(',',''))))
```

If you are doing these sorts of things quite often in your code, making a function as such might be handy:

```
integerify_currency = lambda x:int(float(x.lstrip('$').replace(',','')))
```

Comment: this is working.one more thing this code i use for calculation but after that how can i get data back in original format ?

Comment: @habib original form?? you mean including dollar-sign and commas??